# php search array  which contains "key : value" items

Tags: php, arrays

If i have an array $output that looks like this,  how can i search the array and echo out the duration value which in this case is 30. Duration is not always key [18].

```
Array
(
    [16] =>     hasKeyframes    : true
    [17] =>     hasMetadata     : true
    [18] =>     duration        : 30
    [19] =>     audiosamplerate : 22000
    [20] =>     audiodatarate   : 68
    [21] =>     datasize        : 1103197
}
```

Comment: be so much easier for you, if you re/built your array properly

Comment: @Lawrence This is the array generated from doing `exec('ffmpeg -i video.flv', $output);` I did not make it this way

Comment: but you could rebuild it by looping it with explode(':',$output[$i])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array=preg_grep("/duration/", $output);
$array=implode(",",$array);
$key_value=explode(":",$array);
echo $key_value[1];
```

Comment: This isn't working. What is `$array` in your code. My array name is $output.

Comment: Thanks, it works. All other answers are valid, but this is short and clean. BTW you made a typo `$output))`. It should be `$output)`

Answer (score 5):

Try this function:

```
function search_value($array, $key, $default_value = false)
{
   foreach( $array as $value)
   {
      list($_key, $_val) = array_map('trim', explode(":", $value) );
      if( strtolower($key) == strtolower($_key) )
         return $_val;
   }
   return $default_value;
}
```

**use it like this**:

```
echo search_value( $output, 'duration', 0);
```

**BUT**, just like @Lawrence pointed out, it will be **MUCH** easier if you change your array structure:

```
$output= array(
  'hasKeyframes'=>true,
  'hasMetadata'=>true,
  'duration'=>'30',
  .
  .
  .
);
```

This way, you only have to check if key exist and get that value:

```
echo (!array_key_exists('duration', $output) ? $output['duration'] : 0);
```

Comment: read my comment back to lawrence. this is how `exec()` outputs the array. In your example `search_value($array, $key)` What is `$key`. Do i need to input that in. $key is not known. It's dynamically generated.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend to sanitize the array at first:

```
$sanitized = array();

foreach($output as $value) {
    $data = explode(':', $value);
    $sanitized[trim($data[0])] = trim($data[1]);
}

echo $sanitized['duration'];
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can't you make it associative array instead?

Sure he can:

```
<?php
$output = array(
    16 => 'hasKeyframes    : true',
    17 => 'hasMetadata     : true',
    18 => 'duration        : 30',
    19 => 'audiosamplerate : 22000'
    20 => 'audiodatarate   : 68',
    21 => 'datasize        : 1103197'
);

foreach( $output as $element ) {
    $values = array_map( 'trim', explode( ':', $element ) );
    $assoc[$values[0]] = $values[1];
}


echo isset( $assoc['duration'] ) ? $assoc['duration'] : 'Duration not set.';
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you make it associative array instead?

```
Array
(
    [hasKeyframes] =>    true
    [hasMetadata] =>     true
    [duration] =>        30
    [audiosamplerate] => 22000
    [audiodatarate] =>   68
    [datasize] =>        1103197
}
```

Then it would be simple `$arr['duration']`.

If not, you can parse values, for example in the way like silent posted meanwhile.

Comment: @Pinkie: I agree with Lawrence Cherone who 3 hours ago wrote in comment to question: _but you could rebuild it by looping it with explode(':',$output[$i])_